# Media player for Debian Squeeze

Tags: video

I would like to install a media player, but I don't know what players are available to install. I have tried to install VLC although it does not work. I am using Debian squeeze.

Answer (score 6):

Regardless of distribution, if you want a media player then use [OMXPlayer](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFIQFjAA&url=https://github.com/huceke/omxplayer/&ei=d50CUNPYK6mn0AWd6OmIBw&usg=AFQjCNFe1cStErgCseiG98NFGvo9sPiU1Q&sig2=dhwrOZ4qBbVP_9mWCNfnzA&cad=rja).

It is still the only media player that offers full hardware accelleration (as far as I know). Anything else will provide choppy video playback.

Also, it might be useful for you to know that the Debian Wheezy beta has OMXPlayer installed by default.